# How to know where this function definition is declared?

Tags: php, password

I am new to wordpress, I wanted to know where this definition is mentioned 
in wordpress

```
return apply_filters('check_password', $check, $password, $hash, $user_id);
```

I found it in `pluggable .php` file line no `1470`
I wanted to know this because there are two types of password saved one is simple but with encryption and other is with $P$B infront of encrypted password.
 I wanted to know what is the difference between them and how they are managed.

Please Help.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

To answer your other question, about the two types of passwords stored in the database:

Up until version 2.5, WordPress stored passwords encrypted with the MD5 hashing algorhythm. MD5 is nowadays considered to be poor security - with moderately-priced off-the-shelf GPUs, it takes less than a hour for a program to brute-force all possible combinations of MD5-encrypted passwords up to 6 characters.

Since version 2.5, WordPress encrypts passwords with phpass, a function based on the SHA1 algorhythm, which is better in terms of security (though still not the most advanced algorhythm out there). The 'check_password' filter exists so that plugins can replace the native SHA1-based password hashing with still more secure algorhythms.

The differing passwords you're seeing are most likely the difference between old users who still have MD5 passwords in the system and newer users with the SHA1 passwords. The SHA password hashes begin with "$P$B". If those users log in to the system with their old passwords, WP will update the stored password hash with one using the current algorhythm.

Comment: I'd also like to add that its handy that they have kept the MD5 backwards compatibility in there because you can run this SQL query to reset your password if you ever get locked out: UPDATE wp_users SET user_pass = MD5("password") WHERE ID = 'user id'

Answer (score 2):

apply_filters is a generic function that takes the 'check_password' tag and executes all the functions that have attached themselves to it via the `add_filter` call.

To see which functions are hooking into the 'check_password' filter, use the wordpress hooks database to see all instances here:

http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks

edit: for information on what hooks and filters are, see here http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Hooks.2C_Actions_and_Filters

Comment: what is the meaning of hooking into the 'check_password' filter???

Comment: apply_filters doesn't do the check_password stuff, you need to read up on hooks and filters, they are a critical component of how Wordpress works. Think of a hook as an event, with functions attached to it, and when the hook is fired, all the functions attached are executed one by one. A filter is a hook where each function is given the value, and then does stuff to it, and passes it to the next function/

Comment: Ive ammended the answer with a link to the wordpress codex explaining hooks and filters